Duende IdentityServer - Inconsistent login status across multiple clients
(Originally posted on Duende support forum here but no response so far so thought I'd try stackoverflow.)
Issue
We host our own IdentityServer instance and all client apps are our own.
When a user changes between client apps some time after logging in, some apps consider the user to be logged out while others consider them to be logged in. This is confusing and inconvenient for the user. I think we have probably always (4-5 years or so) had this issue but it has recently become more apparent as we now have multiple clients sharing a host URL behind a reverse proxy.
Setup/Configuration
Our clients are all configured to have a 20 minute id_token, 5 minute access_token and 30 minute refresh_token, most clients use a response type of code with PKCE, an older client uses hybrid flow with code id_token. They use session cookies with a sliding expiration as we want the browser to delete them when the browser is closed.
To Reproduce

Open Client A and login.
Open Client B in a new tab (no need to log in as already logged in).
Refresh a page on Client A every 10 minutes, which keeps the login session alive on Client A.
After more than 20 minutes, refresh a page on Client B - this client will consider the user to be logged out.

At this stage:

Client A on the first tab considers the user to be logged in.
Client B on the second tab considers the user's session to have expired and treats them as not authenticated.

It appears as though Client B is aware that it has been used and that its id_token has expired, but is unable (or doesn't try) to acquire a new one from IdentityServer.
Desired behaviour
If the user has been actively using any of the clients, we would like all clients to behave as though the user is logged in (at least from the point of view of the user's perception). This is more important now that we have clients sharing a URL host, as from the user's point of view they look like one application, some parts of which are logged in while others are not.
How can we achieve this? Please help or point us in the right direction.
Edit 20241212: Removed reference to a Client C, the information about which was incorrect and an unhelpful red herring.

See my post here https://nestenius.se/net/improving-asp-net-core-security-by-putting-your-cookies-on-a-diet/ where we introduce a Cookie Session Store, to better manage and secure your cookies.

There is a lot that you do not explain. HTTP only cookies are issued to apps by some kind of backend for frontend, not by the identity server. You do not explain how your cookie issuing or verification works.
There are  two main deployment models for dealing with multiple apps:
ISOLATED COOKIES MODEL
Most commonly, multiple apps should keep their cookies isolated. Eg you deploy apps on different domains:

https://www.product1.com
https://www.product2.com

You then use Single Sign On (SSO) to navigate across apps. Each app gets its own tokens with its particular API permissions and encrypts them into cookies issued to the browser.
MICRO FRONTENDS
Another possible deployment is a shared cookies model, when all apps are for the same business area:

https://www.product.com/app1
https://www.product.com/app2

A single BFF (eg a utility API) issues cookies to the first app that authenticates the user, who can then seamlessly navigate across apps without SSO redirects.
YOUR DEPLOYMENT
You say that your apps share a host URL but that they each get their own tokens. That suggests to me that:

You might be using .NET server side tech within each app to issue cookies
The cookies are not isolated and might overwrite or conflict with each other somehow

It feels like either a server is not receiving a cookie or receives the wrong cookie, eg one that it cannot decrypt. Where possible I aim to use solutions with good server side logging of cookie verification failures.
I may be able to improve my answer if you provide some lower level details, eg failing HTTP request details, in addition to your description of symptoms.

Thanks Gary, I appreciate the help. As you say, the client apps issue their cookies, IdentityServer is issuing the tokens that are stored in those cookies. Clients A, B and C in my example are 2 .NET 8 Razor Pages apps and a .NET 8 Blazor Server app. They each issue and name their own cookies so they should be isolated even when sharing a host name behind the reverse proxy. The behaviour I see also occurs when I disable the reverse proxy and use separate host names.

I intend to handle more CookieAuthenticationEvents and OpenIdConnectEvents to do more logging and/or use breakpoints to try and understand what is going wrong and where.
If you can be more explicit about what more information you would like me to provide I will do so if I can.

Even if cookies have different names it is not great that App A may send App B's cookies. Note also that an XSS exploit is domain wide and affects all apps. But your direction sounds right - focus on logs and understanding why the server rejects cookies.

After a lot of testing I think I now understand what is going on. I'm posting this as an answer as I think it is probably correct. If/when I get around to implementing a solution I'll come back and mark it as the correct answer.
When the user logs in to our IdentityServer it issues the user with a session cookie so that if they attempt to use any client, IdentityServer will know they are logged in and can issue the relevant tokens without asking them to log in again. The user could use Client A and Client B for a while (from my example in the OP), each of which then issue their own session cookies to the user.
If the user stops using Client B for a while, but continues to use Client A, then the session cookies (or the tokens within them) for Client B and the IdentityServer expire due to the idle timeout.
So if the user attempts to use Client B again, this client thinks they are unauthenticated and redirects to IdentityServer which also thinks they are unauthenticated and prompts them to log in. They are still able to carry on using Client A as its session cookie has been kept alive by its continual use.
This might be what @tore-nestenius was getting at in his comment on the OP, but he left a lot unsaid so I'm not sure if that was just a punt or if he'd recognised all this and jumped straight to a possible solution without an explanation.
I think the solution to this problem will involve storing session information for IdentityServer (and maybe also the client apps) on the server instead of in cookies. Which could enable use of client apps to cause the IdentityServer session to stay alive until 20 minutes after the last use of any client app. It could also provide many other advantages like being able to more easily track who is logged in to what and when using a centralised system.
Duende's Server Side Sessions Inactivity Timeout feature might offer a solution to my problem. The suggestion from @tore-nestenius on how to build a custom server side SessionStore or something based on it, might also do the job.
